# Thread Crash SQLite

Tags: ios, multithreading, sqlite, crash

I am trying to solve problem that when multiple thread called on open `SQLite` database and no get error. I tried if variable *isOpen* and I set it's `= true` before `SQLite` `open` and `close` after `close` and when function called if `isOpen == true` it goes `while loop` and `sleep`. But it didn't worked!

I think I should do `addoperation` I guess I don't know.

[image: https://fbcdn-sphotos-g-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-frc3/t1.0-9/10270477_1376307345988053_2259070264192298056_n.jpg]

[image: https://scontent-a-vie.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ash3/t1.0-9/10155394_1376307385988049_5923218168419158893_n.jpg]

Comment: Are you using dispatch on your project?

Comment: ofcourse @EridBardhaj
but as if i handled it.i tied all thread which is related to database 
on same queque

Comment: What kind of message gives you when it crashes?